# Limit total number of Records divisible by 8 in PHP

Tags: php

Currently i have 93 records in my Table. But i need to show only 88 records. If table has reached 96 records, show all 96 records.

How to limit take total records divided by 8.

Comment: can you share your so far code?

Comment: Without code a proper solution can only guessed. It depends e.g. on based on 0/1, is array, loop...?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it is connected with programming, but:

```
$limit = floor(93 / 8) * 8;  // 88
$limit = floor(96 / 8) * 8;  // 96
```

Or

```
$limit = 93 - (93 % 8);  // 88
$limit = 96 - (96 % 8);  // 96
```

In case when number of records less then 8, just return number of records.

Answer (score 1):

set total only

```
$total=93;
$div=intval($total/8);
$limit=$div*8;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in more than 3 words.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

```
$TotalRecords = 93;
$div=intval($TotalRecords/8);
$recordShow = $div * 8;
```

Comment: There is no benefit to this community to duplicate a code-only answer an hour and 7 minutes later.